# iOS file browser example

Tags: ios, file, browser, explorer

Does anyone have some sample code demonstrating how to make a "file browser" view?  I'd like to be able to navigate through directories and drill-down the sub-directories and see files located within the various folders.  I want the user to be able to create new directories/files and even select an existing file.  Is there sample code out there already available to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about sample code, but this wouldn't be too complicated to achieve using `NSFileManager` and a `UITableView`.

You can obtain arrays of directory contents using the `subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:error` and associated methods of a file manager. These arrays in turn can populate a `UITableView`. It would be fairly easy to put together a navigation controller that could display a series of table views showing a file hiearchy.

Bear in mind, however, that you'll only be able to access the directories inside your application sandbox, unless you're running on a jailbroken device.

Comment: The goal is to mnake use of folder-like hierarchies that do not represent folders/files on the device itself.

Comment: ...it's been two years! Hope you managed to find something that worked for you...if you're not representing files on the device then it's just a matter of parsing whatever data structure you're using and displaying it in a table view - fairly standard stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The iOS programming guide says that

> You should never present users with the list of files in this directory and ask them to decide what to do with those files. Instead, sort through the files programmatically and add files without prompting.

This is assuming you are trying to implement file browse feature for your documents directory.

Comment: Do you know why Apple add this restriction? By the way, I can't find the related content in iOS Programming guide.

Comment: @BobCromwell see the File sharing Support part at the following link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/CoreServicesLayer/CoreServicesLayer.html

Comment: Thanks. However I think the word 'never' is a bit misleading. Apple just gave an advice for better user experience.

Comment: I think it is deliberately intended to avoid giving the user, an illusion of the existence of a file system.

Comment: @Vin Yes, but users may actually have a file system outside of Apple's walled garden (think cloud storage).

Comment: +1 for the quote. I just re-quoted it to a client who wanted a "Browse" button in an app, which naturally raised my heckles slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an author of [FileExplorer](https://github.com/Augustyniak/FileExplorer) which is a file browser for iOS and fulfills most of your requirements.
Here are some of the features of my control:

1. Possibility to choose files or/and directories if there is a need for that
2. Possiblity to remove files or/and directories if there is a need for that
3. Built-in search functionality
4. View Audio, Video, Image and PDF files.
5. Possibility to add support for any file type.

You can find my control [here](https://github.com/Augustyniak/FileExplorer).

Comment: Can it be used with remote file systems and other hierarchical-based items?

Comment: @gonzobrains Unfortunately FileExplorer supports only one hierarchical-based system - file system.